# How to change design of title and snippet above google maps marker

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, location

i am currently working on an application involving google maps.
I want to change the design of the information above the location marker. But i cannot figure out how to do this.

To explain;

i have this:

[image: Map with standard info window]

and i want this:

[image: Design for custom info window]

I have the design for the blue box as an image. But i do not know if i need to use the image or write code to make it look like the image.

Here is the code i have so far:

**MainActivity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     LocationListener {

    GoogleMap map;
    LatLng myPosition;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isLocationEnabled(this);


    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    // remove geolocation button
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        LatLng amsterdam = new LatLng(52.3667, 4.9000);


        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition);
        // setting custom marker
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker));

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(myPosition);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker));
        markerOptions.title(" Title");

        markerOptions.snippet(" Here comes the address ");


        // create and add marker
        Marker locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        // always show info text
        locationMarker.showInfoWindow();
        // opening maps zoomed in at current location
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(amsterdam, 17.0f));



    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


}

public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    } else {
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }


    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/abc_action_bar_title_item" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Excuse me in advance if i used sloppy coding or bad practices. These files are a playground for me to create the functionality so that i can put it in the actual application later on.

Answer (score 3):

To change the look of the info window ("the information above the location marker"), you use an `InfoWindowAdapter`. In your case, you want to replace the whole window, both the contents and the frame (the thing with the caret that points to the marker). So, your `InfoWindowAdapter` would implement `getInfoWindow()` and return the `View` to use for the given `Marker`. You then call `setInfoWindowAdapter()` on your `GoogleMap` to tell it to ask your `InfoWindowAdapter` for the `View` to use when the user taps on a `Marker`.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/ImagePopups) demonstrates the concept, though I override `getInfoContents()` instead of `getInfoWindow()`, as I wanted to replace the contents but use the existing info window frame. You wind up with something like this:

[image: MapsV2/ImagePopups Sample Screenshot]