# android googleMap - how to add a InfoWindow without tooltip arrow

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

take a look at this image how the InfoWindow appears and its different then the one google provides i think?

[image]

I am searching for a text box like this with no tooltip arrow.  when i checked android google maps feature it looks like this:

[sample googleMap snippet, notice the arrow](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLVAV.png&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357062/how-to-change-design-of-title-and-snippet-above-google-maps-marker&docid=h1RIq0YlWPjQIM&tbnid=QwsAburQiysjnM:&vet=1&w=1280&h=768&source=sh/x/im)

How would i hide the arrow? i've like to change the anchorpoint to be the left top of the textbox also. is this all customization ?

Comment: I do not know anything about Snippet . But this is the same case with Info Window on Map.. When you use a Custom Layout for `InfoWindow` the arrow will not appear. Check if there is an option for using a Custom layout for Snippet too .

Comment: i think you have to make it custom message layout. and show and hide it according to your need on google maps.

Answer (score 1):

this is really easy to do with [iconGenerator](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html) from google map util library:

```
 val iconGenerator = IconGenerator(activity)
    val window = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myinfo_window,null)
    iconGenerator.setContentView(window)
    iconGenerator.setBackground(activity.getDrawableCompat(R.drawable.mybox_bg))
    return googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon())))
```

myinfo_window.xml then looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:padding="13dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cool LOCATION"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

note: **R.drawable.mybox_bg** is a 9 patch drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add info window to google map.

static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();

Comment: the question says without a tooltip arrow.  i think this way yields an arrow right ? let me know if im wrong.

Comment: @For that you've to make custom infowindow.

Comment: You can refer this link https://androidhumanrobot.blogspot.com/2014/11/custom-info-window-in-google-map-android.html